# Error trying to debug javascript on vscode

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I restarted learning javascript and I'm coding in a github folder, when I try to debug it on VSCode I get this error:

> (node:13088) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
> (Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

And this is my code:

```js
const textSize = "Text".length;
console.log(textSize)
```

Hope someone can help with it

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really an error, that is a warning. How are you running this exactly?

Comment: Is this your entire code? This code shouldn’t throw an error on its own

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673860/vscode-extension-deprecation-warning-buffer-how-to-diagnose/68413237?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.3351#68413237 It is not a problem with your code but a library that vscode uses.

Comment: So, I`m trying to use the own javascript runner of vscode, then i press f5 to run, it shows the upper window of the debugger (with play, pause, etc.) and this is the only message i get, no answer from the code itself.

Comment: Well, that is just a warning.  It would not prevent your code from running.  Your `console.log` should appear right below it.  You have a different issue.