# Follow tutorial to make a helloworld vscode extension and get buffer error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I followed the tutorial exactly at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

then i get

`(node:10929) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`

when I press `F5` to build and run the helloworld extension

Seems most of the errors come from this bootstrap-fork.js

[image]

I don't know how to resolve.

- node is v17.0.1
- npm is v8.0.1
- vscode is as follows:

```
version: 1.62.3
Commit: ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
Date: 2021-11-17T07:59:13.865Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 13.5.2
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.6.0
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Ignore this warning, it has to be fixed by the VSC team, or Electron team

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673860/vscode-extension-deprecation-warning-buffer-how-to-diagnose/68413237?r=SearchResults&s=1|42.7446#68413237 for more on the deprecation warnings - probably not anything you can avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore and carry on as per advised by the other commenters.

Tested on monterey. Same thing happened.

```
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:38:17.605Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.2.0
```

VS code version on monterey