# How to fix this error when I am creating vscode extention

Tags: vscode-extensions

> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Comment: Can you share your entire project somewhere? I cannot reproduce any of the errors.

Comment: Here is an answer with steps to investigate deprecation warnings when creating extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68413237/836330

Comment: @LexLi

Tannks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the messages are errors, but warnings and you will probably not be able to fix them. It depends on where the mentioned modules are imported from. If you have dependencies to them, you can easily use a later version, with those problems fixed. But more likely they are 4th party dependencies, which would require to get a newer version of your 3rd party dependencies (if there's any) that hopefully links to newer version of the 4th party deps.

Another possible solution is to add an own (3rd party) dependency in your package.json to newer versions of these libraries. They are automatically deduped by NPM, but might cause trouble with the 3rd libraries that use them.

So, if you are unsure what to do, you can ignore the warnings for now and keep your 3rd party list dependencies updated, in the hope that those libs sooner or later are updated to use a newer 4th party lib.