# "DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated..." When trying to create vscode extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a new vscode extension.

I've followed the guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), and created my extension using the following commands:

```bash
npm install --global yo generator-code
yo code
```

When trying to run the extension without any changes I get this error:

```
Checking whether to register object drop extension

Registering object drop provider

Registered object drop provider

(node:40106) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `Code Helper (Plugin) --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I am using Node.js v20.3.0 on Mac

Comment: that error is there for years already, just ignore

Comment: Either `yo` or `generator-code` (or a package they depend on) has a call to the long deprecated `new Buffer()` constructor. You *could* do what the message suggests, ie turn on `--trace-deprecation` and file an issue with the respective package. You could even provide a fix for that issue, once you traced it down. But typically, for now just ignore it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68413237/836330 basically a duplicate.

Comment: @rioV8 The issue is that the extension does load :(

Comment: @derpirscher It is not the extension code that calls `Buffer()`, somewhere in the VSC API it is called. As long as it is not removed from Node there is no problem